# Rails conditional scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, conditional-statements

i wrote this scope for my User model but it isn't working because of the 'or'.
How can i do ?

```
scope :offline, ->{ where((online: false).or(name: 'Undefined')) }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
scope :offline, lambda { where( "online = ? OR name = ?", false, 'undefined') }
```